# Left-handed tremolo on a right-handed Jazzmaster

Tags: electric-guitar, tremolo-system, lefties

I've developed the habit of having the trem bar under my wrist and pressing down on it with my wrist when playing my Mexican Fender Jazzmaster. The trem bar runs at a 45° angle across the strings and gets in the way of picking or strumming sometimes, and I think it would be easier if it were attached to the top of the trem system instead of to the bottom; which made me wonder: **can you put a tremolo system from a left-handed Jazzmaster in a right-handed one?** They look symmetrical, but maybe the body routing isn't? Are there any other reasons not to try this?

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you are going to have to strip the mechanism off the guitar, and see for yourself if it's symmetrical. If yes, it's good to go. If not, then it's out with the router. No big deal either way, just extra work for the latter.

Answer (score 2):

There are plenty of technical drawings for guitar routings on the Internet, and they all agree that the routing for standard Jazzmaster tremolo cavity is symmetrical. It might be worth it to check your guitar before ordering anything, but there's a good chance that left-handed tremolo will fit.

Answer (score 1):

I am a lefty and done the same thing in reverse. I use a righthand tremolo on a lefty guitar. It works great. Plus no reaching to grab the arm. It fit just fine on mine, so should for you. It a 6 hole setup the same for either hand.